# Error: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to enforce integrity so that a Person can't loan a book more than once a day. The tables & trigger compiles without errors but and i get the above error when u try to insert. I can't fix it. Syntax:

```
create or replace trigger chk_DateL
for insert or update on lending
COMPOUND TRIGGER
--declare
L_Date number(1);
avail varchar2(10);
subtype copy_booksRec is lending%ROWTYPE;
type copied_bks is table of copy_booksRec;
cbks copied_bks := copied_bks();

after each row is 
begin
  cbks.extend;
  cbks(cbks.last).cb_num := :new.cb_num;
  cbks(cbks.last).sb_num := :new.sb_num;
end after each row;

after statement is
begin
  for i in cbks.first .. cbks.last loop
    select loancode into avail from copy_books where num = cbks(i).cb_num;
    select count(date_L) into L_Date from lending where sb_num = cbks(i).sb_num and date_L = cbks(i).date_L;
      if (L_Date = 0) then
        insert into Lending values (cbks(i).cb_num, cbks(i).sb_num, cbks(i).date_L);
        update copy_books set loancode = 'Not' where num = cbks(i).cb_num;
--        cbks(i).date_L := cbks(i).date_L;
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('You can only make ONE LOAN in a day! You have already loaned a book on ' || L_Date);
      cbks.delete;
    end if;
  end loop;
  end after statement;
end chk_DateL;
/
show errors
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a unique index on `Lending(cb_num, sb_num, date_L)`?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop

```
FORALL i IN cbks.first .. cbks.last
    insert into lending values cbks(i);
```

inserts into the lending table, which causes the trigger to be executed again. So the trigger stacks upon itself until 50 levels are reached, then oracle stops this by throwing the error.

Comment: i removed the insert stmt from this position and replaced it with the date_L allocation in the if stmt above but it still raises the same error code upon insertion. The new syntax is above now. Ps, i need a solution other than placing a unique index. Tnx

Comment: That won't change anything; you still call `insert into lending` from within a trigger on the lending table.

Comment: i dont understand the reason here. I have a couple of other triggers i created this way but they all work fine. Just like this, they are triggers created on table1, which also insert into the same table1. They use the FORALL…stmt & still work fine in 11g. Plz, what do i need to change here?

Comment: Oh, i understand the problem now. Tnx for ur suggestion. ^^